# Cash on delivery payment method restricted for specific zip codes

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, cash-on-delivery, zipcode

I need disable cash on delivery method restricted for specific zip codes.

I use IWD One Page Checkout for my project

Answer (score 0):

try below for checkout page , All you need is to edit the file `/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method`/Cashondelivery.php

```
public function getInstructions()
        {
            return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
        }

        public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
        if ($quote) {

            // Here is the list of restricted Zip Codes
            $restrictedZips = array(
    '641004'
    ,'641006'


    );

            $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();

            if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
    }
```